# Microsoft Arc Touch Mouse doesn't start

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, mouse, bluetooth

I've tried countless of blog-posts and other things to get this to work but I'm running out of ideas and options here. I just bought the Microsoft Arc Touch Mouse and it doesn't start, at all. When I plug it in it says that "a device needs additional settings" and then it says that the device is ready for use:

[image: Undergoing Setup]

[image: Setup completed]

In the Blueetoth & other devices I can see two things: Microsoft Wireless Transceiver under 'other devices' as well as Arc Touch Mouse under 'Mouse, keyboard & pen':

[image]

The problem is that it doesn't work. The batteries in it are new, it flashes with a green light when I arc it and the blue pointer is constantly on (albeit flickering intensly but I assume that's normal?)

**Computer specs**

- Dell Latitude E7440
- Windows 10 with all windows updates

**Troubleshooting done so far:**

- Tried turning it off and on again
- Tried to 'Remove device' from the bluetooth settings unplugging and plugging it in to reinstall it
- Tried to change the Bluetooth Support Service to run with Local System (another forum post recommended it)
- Used the hardware troubleshooting in Windows
- Used the bluetooth troubleshooting in Windows
- Removed all the 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power' for all my bluetooth and mouse devices from Device Manager
- Updated drivers (not the mouse though, explained in next point) and restarted the computer
- Tried installing the 'Mouse and keyboard center' but that doesn't give you any options to download any drivers, which I find strange because there seems to be no ability for you to download drivers for this device. The official MS page for this only has the link to the Mouse and keyboard center 3.0 download but no actual drivers.

Anyone have any ideas here? I don't know where to keep going here. I have 2 suspicions:

1. Without the Mouse and keyboard center installed the device manager doesn't show anything other than 'HID-compliant mouse' under Mice and other pointing devices:
   [image]

   If I have the Mouse and keyboard center installed it shows up as Microsoft USB Dual Receiver Wireless Mouse (Mouse and Keyboard center):
   [image]

   This makes me think that something happens when it automatically installs itself as device manager doesn't recognise it as Arc Touch Mouse (although the new Bluetooth and other devices interface does show it as Arc Touch Mouse in the first picture so I'm not sure.)
2. Under device manager it doesn't show up under bluetooth devices but rather under the Mice and other pointing devices. This particular setting doesn't allow me to change any Power Management settings as it isn't a wireless device - maybe this could be the reason?

Any help here is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

So I found the Arc Touch Bluetooth Mouse app on the Windows Store and downloaded that. When opening this app it says "Connect your mouse to edit settings" while in the Bluetooth and other devices says that both the transceiver and the mouse are connected so there's definitely something fishy going on here.

Comment: You can give it a try with a different PC, but it sounds like the mouse is faulty and you should RMA it. I have one ([not a good choice if you middle-click much](https://superuser.com/q/770983/194694)) and it just works everywhere as soon as you plug it in, no extra drivers or setup required.

Comment: Yeah that was my next step, won't be able to do that for a few hours though but I found a similar post on the TechNet forum which suggested that the mouse might be dead. I actually hope that it is a faulty device because if it's not I'm all out of ideas :)

Comment: Yepp, it was a damaged device. Got it replaced for a new one and it worked perfectly! If you want to post the "have you tried it on a different computer to verify it's not a hardware issue?" as an answer I can mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a try with a different PC, but it sounds like the mouse is faulty and you should RMA it. I have one and it just works everywhere as soon as you plug it in, no extra drivers or setup required.

<sub>(reposted from comments)</sub>